# How to find if the image has black rectangles of size greater than 5*5

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to write a program in c# or c++, which finds if the image (png or jpg) has a rectangle which is black in color and is greater than size 5 * 5 pixels. If there are multiple such rectangles in an image, it should be able to give me the coordinates of all such rectangles which are black in color.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an [Image Correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_image_correlation):

[image]